# Adding a container view to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicontainerview

I am trying to add a container view to a `UICollectionViewCell` in interface builder but Xcode issues an error `error: Illegal Configuration: Container Views cannot be placed in elements that are repeated at runtime.`  Will making the `UICollectionViewCell` static would solve this?  If so, how would you make the UICollectionViewCell static?

Comment: There is no static collection view. What is your purpose for adding a container view to a cell? Perhaps there's another way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I have collection view with two sections.  Section one contains a single video.  Section two contains a collection of photos arranged in 3 columns which the user can re-arrange (so I can't use tableview here.)  I would like to the user to be able to play the video in-place -- not transition over to another view controller (AVPlayerViewController).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I guess you are trying to do, is placing a UIViewController into a dynamically generated UITableViewCell. 
If so, this isn't possible if the cell you are generating are dynamic. If you know a priori that the cells will always be in a fixed number, you can generate them by Interface builder setting the cells to static.

If instead you only want to add a container view to your cell in order to put other objects in it, you need to add a UIView object, not a UIViewController.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Well, I ended up adding the view property of the `MPMoviePlayerController` to the contentView of the cell (as you mentioned).  Everything works fine.  I am a little concern about not having a consistent views/view controllers hierarchy with this approach -- as caution by this video `Implementing UIViewController Containment` `https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/` at 16:41.

Comment: say how the heck do you set the cells to static in a collection view ??!

Comment: @Fattie in Interface Builder (aka Storyboard) there is a setting in the right menu that allows you to set the cell template static or dynamic

Comment: hi @Lolloz89 ! thanks for the reply - I think they DO NOT HAVE THAT for collection views - only for table views ....... ????  I do not see it for collection views ......  :O